# Determine effect of price change on items

Tags: inference, experiment-design

I work for a company that will be changing the prices of a group of items across the chain of stores. My question is, what is the best way to try and determine what the effect is of that price change? A/B testing is not an option due to workflow complexity and cost. So, what is the next best way?

For example, say, item A currently costs 5 dollars across the chain. We now are going to change the price to be 4 dollars across the chain. How big of an impact is this having on sales? Is there a way to model this? Or some other statistical method?

Thanks!

Comment: Do users often purchase items repeatedly?  What information do you have about these users, i.e. how rich of a description do you have of your users? Do you have purchase level data, i.e., one record for every purchase?  Do you have shopping level data, i.e., data on customers who were interested in pruchasing an item but didi not?  How rich of a description do you have of the time component?

Comment: We have about as rich of a guest demographic segment as legally able. We do also have purchase level data. Since this is affecting stores currently, we aren't able to tell if a guest was interested in purchasing an item, but ultimately didn't - we could better decipher that via web analytics for guests shopping online, but not in stores.